# Writing a wrapper function computing the memory in use

Tags: function-construction, memory

Is there any way I can write a wrapper that wraps around a piece of code and evaluates how much memory has been used after the execution? Ideally I would like a function that performs the following operation

```
m0=MemoryinUse[];
temp=Table[Random[], {i,1,10000}];
output=MemoryinUse[]-m0
```

The code to be input in this function has to be arbitrarily long.

Comment: How about ByteCount[temp]?

Comment: It does the job but I would prefer to see some example code that's not an inbuilt Mathematica function. In my code I find situations like this all the time, and maybe the example is too trivial but learning how to write it from scratch would be cool

Answer (score 4):

For a `AbsoluteTiming` sort of `{value, result}` output, maybe this:

```
memoryused = 
  Function[code, {MemoryInUse[] + #1, #2} &[-MemoryInUse[], code], 
   HoldAll];
```

Or this:

```
ClearAll[memoryused];
SetAttributes[memoryused, HoldAll];
memoryused[code_] := Module[{m0, res},
   m0 = MemoryInUse[];
   res = code;
   {MemoryInUse[] - m0, res}
   ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to the question that doesn't require using the Mathematica inbuilt function ByteCount. The merit of this is that it takes two snapshots of the memory usage before the code is executed and after, which is a good way to evaluate background memory usage as well.

The idea is to take the code as a string input to the function and execute it within it. Here's a function that implements this

```
memoryused[string_]:=Module[{m0},
m0=MemoryInUse[];
ToExpression[string];
MemoryInUse[]-m0
];
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by _write it from scratch_ or _not an inbuilt Mathematica function_. In your answer, you are still using ``MemoryInUse[]``, which is a built-in Mathematica function ...

Comment: Right! That was awkward phrasing. I had a specific goal in mind, that I edited in my answer.

Comment: No need for the side-effect of setting `output` to the difference, the last evaluation result is returned.